# Class that returns objects of the same type from two different sources depending on context

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two databases, and depending on context I need to retrieve records (of the same type) from either one. How should I design the class that will retrieve the objects from the database, is there a better way than passing the database ceonnection string as a constructor to the class?

Comment: Are you using any kind of ORM or DB adapter to interact with the db, or straight up stored procedures?

Comment: You need to look into an IoC (inversion of control) / DI (dependency injection) framework, such as StructureMap or Unity, to inject the corresponding connection string or data context. What is the context that differentiates which db to poll?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - using a simple SqlDataReader, no ORM

Comment: @FreshCode - i actually synchronize generate a list of differences between the records in the two database, I read the record in DB A, then I read the records in DB B, and I compare them one by one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only difference in the whole implementation is the connection string I would stick with that no need to complicate matters.

Answer (score 0):

If both DBs use the same driver, I don't see any problem with what you're doing. Although actually, I think I'd keep both connection strings as constants in your data access class, and then pass a key to the class to tell it which one to use. Dependency injection, while a really cool and useful tool, would be killing a fly with a bazooka for this one.